# Can't display number correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I'm working on a money management program. There's an input box that you have to type your earnings into. Whenever I input my number and click enter, the number appears on the side but when I add another number it doesn't add up correctly.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Edit title -->
    <title>Banking App</title>
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">

    <header>
        <h1>Bank Account Manager</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="displayInfo">
        <div class="displayBalance">
            <h2 class="displayBalanceTag">Balance: <span class="displayBalanceNumber"></span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputInfo">
        <center>
            <input type="text" name="earned" placeholder="How Much Have You Earned?" class="earned">
            <input type="text" name="spent" placeholder="How Much Have You Spent?" class="spent">
        </center>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Main.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// VARIABLES
var balance; //stores users balance
var earnings; //stores users earnings

var earned = $(".earned"); //input users earnings
var spent = $(".spent"); //input users spendings
var displayBalanceNumber = $(".displayBalanceNumber"); //displays users balance

// START
$("document").ready(function () {
    balance = 0;

    init();
})

// INIT
function init() {
    reset(); //resets everything
    $(earned).bind("keypress", addEarnings);
}

function addEarnings(e) {
    //check for keycode 13 ( enter key )
    if(e.which === 13) {
        earnings = $(this).val(); //get value from input
        balance = balance + earnings;
        displayBalanceNumber.html(balance);
        displayBalanceNumber.html(balance);
    }
}

// RESET
function reset() {
    displayBalanceNumber.html(balance); //make value inside balance holder to 0
}
```

Comment: In what way is it incorrect? What numbers do you enter and what result do you get?

Comment: ^ also what do you expect to get?

Comment: Should be `earnings = +$(this).val();`

Comment: Actually, I think I can guess your problem  `earnings = $(this).val();` followed by `balance = balance + earnings;` - in that case `earnings` will be a string so you will not be doing addition, you are doing string concatenation. E.g., `1 + "2" //12`. Instead of that, do `Number($(this).val())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line, `balance = balance + earnings;`, sees `earnings` as a string. When you add a string to a number, it converts all of it to a string. What you need to do is convert `earnings` to an integer. Replace that line with `balance = balance + +earnings;`. The `+` converts `earnings` to an number.